# C++ - terminology of an idiom

Tags: c++, terminology, idioms

This idiom helped me solving several problems, but I don't know how this is called, googling didn't help. Its purpose is to store different template classes in a heterogeneous collection, a well-known example usage is `std::any`.

```
class TemplateBase
{
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~TemplateBase() {}
};

template<typename T>
class TemplateImplementation : public TemplateBase
{
    T data;
public:
    virtual void f() override
    {
        // some T-specific implementation
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TemplateBase>> collection;
collection.emplace_back(new TemplateImplementation<int>{1});
collection.emplace_back(new TemplateImplementation<std::string>{"hello"});
```

Comment: "Type erasure" is the term you're looking for.

Comment: Indeed, missed the inheritance. Fixed OP, sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2872/type-erasure

Comment: How come there's a "buzzword-compliance" tag, but no "buzzword-bingo" tag?

Answer (score 0):

[GManNickG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gmannickg) answered in comments to OP, the idiom is called **Type erasure**. Thanks!